# How to recreate canvas in multiple divs?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have test poll and there are a lot of charts which i need to clean before redrawing them. I was looking for solution and the only one i found was to recreate canvas. So i was trying to remove them all (removing works fine) then recreate, but for some reason all canvas got created on the first div (#chart-center) only.

Here is the code i was using:

```
$(".test-question").each(function () {  
    $('canvas').remove();  
    $('#chart-center').append("<canvas></canvas>");  
});
```

Any thoughts? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi Darius and welcome to SO.  Can you please show us more code. From provided code it is obvious that you appending only one <canvas> div to #chart-center  control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution would be to delete them step by step and find the inner `canvas` and replace it there.

```
$(".test-question").each(function () {  
    $(this).find('canvas').remove();  
    $(this).find("#chart-center").append("<canvas></canvas>"); 
});
```

You should also never use the same id's: use classes instead!

Another solution would be to clear your canvas like this:

```
$(".test-question").each(function () {  
    let canvas = $(this).find("canvas").get(0);
    let c = canvas.getContext('2d');
    c.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
});
```